# I want to store in a variable (via loop) names of .jpg files in current folder

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

for `BAT` file when I write following script I don't get the name of the `.jpg` files in the folder. What's the error and how it can be achieved?

```
for /f "tokens=*" %%f in ('dir /b *.jpg') do (

SET newname=%%f

SET front=%newname:~0,6%
echo %front%

)
```

Answer (score 0):

When a compound statement enclosed in parentheses is to be executed,
the statement is first parsed from the open parenthesis all of the
way to the matching close-parenthesis.

At this time, any `%var%` is replaced by that `var`'s value from the 
environment **AT THE TIME IT IS PARSED** (ie its **PARSE-TIME** value.)

**THEN** if the statement seems valid, it is executed.

There are three common ways of accessing the **RUN-TIME** value of the
variable (as a `FOR` loop executes, for instance.)

1/ `SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION` which switches to a mode where
!var! may be used to access the runtime value of `var`
2/ `CALL set var2=%%var%%` to set the value of `var2` from the 
runtime value of `var`
3/ Executing a subroutine, internal or external within which `%var%` 
will be the runtime value.

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
FOR %%i IN (1 2 3) DO (
ECHO START of run %%i
ECHO using ^!time^! : !time! - PARSE TIME was %time%
CALL ECHO using CALL %%%%TIME%%%% : %%TIME%%
CALL :report
timeout /t 5
ECHO using ^!time^! : !time!
CALL ECHO using CALL %%%%TIME%%%% : %%TIME%%
CALL :report
ECHO END of run %%i
ECHO.
)
GOTO :eof

:report
ECHO :report says TIME is %TIME%
GOTO :eof
```

A few items to note:

1. The instruction

   IF ERRORLEVEL n echo errorlevel is n OR GREATER

   ***ALWAYS*** interprets the RUN-TIME value of `ERRORLEVEL`
2. `IF SET VAR` ***ALWAYS*** interprets the RUN-TIME value of `VAR`
3. The `magic variables` like ERRORLEVEL and TIME should never
   be SET. If you execute

   SET ERRORLEVEL=dumb

then `ERRORLEVEL` will adopt the value `dumb` because the current
value in the environment takes priority over the system-assigned value.

Comment: Now I'm copying a large text block from my cmd textbook concerning delayed expansion to paste it here every day ..... :-)

Answer (score 0):

This is one option - but ! characters in the filenames will cause issues.

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
for /f "delims=" %%f in ('dir /b *.jpg') do (
SET "newname=%%f"
SET "front=!newname:~0,6!"
echo !front!
)
pause
```